# Prevent special characters in android browsers by JQuery

Tags: android, jquery, jsp, ascii

My issue is very clear and I will go direct to the point.

I have registration form and the user is not allowed to type some characters as (Arabic letter and special characters), So I used JQuery to do that and it worked fine in windows browsers and in iOS browsers but I faced a problem in Android browsers, Here is my code :

```
$("#NonArabic").keypress(function(event) {
                var ew = event.keyCode || event.which;
                if (1 <= ew && ew <= 126 && ew != 38)
                    return true;
                return false;
            });
$("[name='NationalID']").keypress(function(event) {
                var ew = event.which;
                if (48 <= ew && ew <= 57 || ew <= 32)
                    return true;
                return false;
            });

$("[name='FullName']").keypress(function(event) {
                var ew = event.which;
                if (47 >= ew || ew >= 58)
                    return true;
                return false;
            });
```

"NoneArabic" is the ID of the form and the others are input fields, the wired thing is that the "NationalID" input field only accepts numbers as you can see the validation and it works fine in all environments (including android browsers), but the "FullName" input field supposed to accept letters only, Although I'm using the same validation way but it's not working in android browsers.
Note: I'm using JSP and Jquery.

So does anyone ever dealt with something like that or know where I went wrong !!

I hope that it's clear and thanks in advance.

Comment: What device are you using? Testing in chrome using Device Mode set to  Samsung Galaxy Note 3 your code works

Comment: @DelightedD0D testing on device modeon chrome  was correct but on real devices went wrong, I tested it on Sony experia z2 and Samsung Galaxy s4, and both gave the same results.